# getting url values in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, url, mobile

i am trying to get the value attached in the url using jquery mobile.

http://localhost/testing/nothing.html#details?id=0&color=blue

I want to get the id = 0 and color = blue using jquery mobile when i go to the "details" page:

$('#details').live('pagecreate',function(event)
{

});

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Please check [this](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/url-parameters-jquery/) link

Write the fucnction like shown below

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
return results[1] || 0;
```

}

To get a particular value just call the function and pass the name of the parameter

```
    $.urlParam('id');
```

Comment: Perfect small snippet of code.  Tested on Desktop browsers using JQM.  Need to test on a Phonegap app still.