# Get param value from a URL in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have got a page called servicesDetails.html that has links.The url looks like below

```
../Myapp/servicesDetails.html?servicetype=Advanced&serviceid=1208
```

The links when clicked loads an internal page called **audioListPage** with some params,the link looks like this

```
<a href="#audioListPage?audioid=123&audiotype=mp3" class="loadAudio" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">
```

Once the audioListPage is loaded the url changes to

```
../Myapp/servicesDetails.html?servicetype=Advanced&serviceid=1208#audioListPage?audioid=123&audiotype=mp3
```

I need to display the user with the audioid and audiotype when the audioListPage loads,how do i do this?

Based on a comment below I tried this

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
return results[1] || 0;
}

$('#audioListPage').live('pagecreate',function(event) {
   console.log($.urlParam('audioid '));//this is giving me an error
});
```

I checked why the error was occuring and found that window.location.href is giving me only
../Myapp/servicesDetails.html?servicetype=Advanced&serviceid=1208, not the updated URL.Im not sure if Im calling the $.urlParam() at the right event

Comment: did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075582/getting-url-values-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get URL parameter with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM Documentation suggests using one of these plugins for parameters:

> jQuery Mobile does not support query parameter passing to
>   internal/embedded pages but there are two plugins that you can add to
>   your project to support this feature. There is a lightweight [page
>   params plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router)
>   for use with backbone.js or spine.js.

- https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params
- https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router

Docs: ( See Known limitations section )

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse `window.location.hash`

See this example:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

and replace `window.location.search`

with `window.location.hash`

Comment: $('#audioListPage').live('pagecreate',function(event) {
   console.log(window.location.hash);//returns empty string
}); Its returning an empty string